# Mobile redirect/forward to tel://

Tags: javascript, android, redirect, tel

I am trying to understand why the below works on desktop but not via android mobile:

```
<script>
window.location.replace("tel://023222244546");
</script>
```

I have tried many redirects but none are working on mobile device. I know with href on click it would work but I am trying to achieve this onload

Comment: As far as I know, mobile browsers "understands" `a` tag with `href` of "tel://", and converts it to native action (open phone app).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "//"

```
<script>
window.location.replace("tel://023222244546");
</script>
```

see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#section-8